# Using composer to better manage my dependencies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, composer-php, bower

I am trying to properly organized my files, and my website is PHP based. Hence, I have installed composer to help me achieve that.

My site also has front end dependencies such as jquery and my question is that once i have installed them in composer how do i load them into a page such as index.php. To be more specific, in the past i would individally write all of the js file require with their respective path in a given page, but now since all of them is taken care of by composer, how do i load jquery into my page.

Below is how my composer looks like, and i tried using `require('vendor/autoload.php')` but that doesn't seem to load the jquery files:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "^2.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^2.3",
        "frameworks/jquery": "^2.1"
    }
}
```

I have heard that it's best to use bower to manage front end dependencies, and composer for back-end, and if so I would like to know why. At the end of the day I do not want to write each individual require file in a page  and ensure that each file are well aligned (such as the global jquery before any specific jquery file), but rather have one file that loads the requirements and where by a push of command can all be updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend Bower, if you'd like to dig in more to css/js development. There also Gulp, if you want to get most out of Bower. I've learned them both but it took a while.

If you just need those css/js files and process them by yourself, I'd recommend trying composer way. For assets (front-end dependencies) there is a composer extension https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin

Comment: thank you for your response. is it good pratice to use both bower and composer? and if i move forward with only composer with the extension you suggested, how would i include the require js file in a particular file such as index.php

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd recommend it in the long term. For managing assets in PHP you can use [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) or some other solutions. It's nice, that with Bower + Gulp you don't have to take care of any of these. You just get one css and one js file as output and use it as you like.

Comment: could you kindly elaborate on how i would use assetic, in particular how would i include the require jquery file inside a file like for instance contact.php

Comment: I would like to, but I don't use it. I use Gulp minimalization a grouping to single file. This might be good for start: http://stefanimhoff.de/2014/gulp-tutorial-12-optimize-css-javascript-images-and-html/